# Identify and annotate group wise minimum values using data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I need to identify the smallest `value` *(ignoring NAs)* for each `class` in the sample data and tag it as 'min' in new column as shown below using `data.table`

Sample data:

```
df = structure(list(class = c("apple", "apple", "apple", "banana", 
"banana", "berry", "berry", "grape", "grape", "grape", "grape", 
"grape", "melon", "melon", "melon"), value = c(108816872, 108851837, 
108890411, 108784778, NA, 108784778, 108816872, 108816872, 108850460, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("class", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Desired output:

```
#    class     value anno
#1   apple 108816872  min
#2   apple 108851837   NA
#3   apple 108890411   NA
#4  banana 108784778  min
#5  banana        NA   NA
#6   berry 108784778  min
#7   berry 108816872   NA
#8   grape 108816872  min
#9   grape 108850460   NA
#10  grape        NA   NA
#11  grape        NA   NA
#12  grape        NA   NA
#13  melon        NA   NA
#14  melon        NA   NA
#15  melon        NA   NA
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was going to suggest @eddies approach, but here's an alternative

```
setDT(df)[order(value), min := c("min", rep(NA, .N - 1)), by = class]
```

---

Edit, if you want the actuall value instead of "min", you could modify to

```
setDT(df)[order(value), min := c(value[1L], rep(NA, .N - 1L)), by = class]
```

Comment: The second approach will give identical result as eddis approach [in my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146189/identify-and-annotate-group-wise-minimum-values-using-data-table-in-r/31146636?noredirect=1#comment50303912_31146573). But with the first one, as I've mentioned, you will need additional step of `df[is.na(value), min := NA]`  if you want to avoid that. Either way, eddies approach is the idiomatic `data.table` approach (which he himself  invented btw) until [.SD will be optimized](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/735)

Comment: Yeah you are right, your second approach is more efficient in terms of speed compared to eddi's creative answer!

Answer (score 6):

```
dt = as.data.table(df) # or convert in place using setDT

dt[dt[, .I[which.min(value)], by = class]$V1, anno := 'min']
```

Comment: Also how can I put the minimum value in place of "min"

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar just change `"min"` to `value` as in `dt[dt[, .I[which.min(value)], by = class]$V1, anno := value]`